# Float a DIV toward bottom-right using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have three DIV and inside the DIV, I would like to float the "Learn More" to bottom right so it will be on top of the grey background.

[image: three div]

### CSS

```css
/* the div for LEARN MORE */
#trt {
    z-index: 9999999999999;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    bottom: 0; // not working
    top: 12; //not working
}

/* the entire div */
.main .cols { padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 10px; }
.main .cols .col { width: 315px; height: 108px; float: left;  background: url(images/tempf.png) no-repeat 0 0; }
.main .cols .col:after { content:''; width: 100%; clear: both; }
.main .cols .col + .col { padding-left: 20px; }
.main .cols .col img.hid { float: left; width: 129px; height: 108px;  }
.main .cols .col-cnt { width: 183px; float: right; }
.main .cols .col .more { font-weight: bold; color: #0206AA; }
```

### HTML

```html
<div class="main">              
    <section class="cols">
        <div class="col">
            <a href="link.aspx">
                <img class="hid" src="css/images/orgNews.png" alt="" />
            </a>
            <div class="col-cnt">
                <h3 style="color: #FFFFFF;">Organization News</h3>
                <p style="color: #FFFFFF;">Interfaith Medical Center related news and updates</p>
                <div id="trt">
                    <img src="css/images/arrow.png" width=11 height=11 align=absmiddle />
                    <a href="link.asp" class="more">Learn More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

### CSS - After Edit

```css
.trt {
    z-index: 9999999999999;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3px;
    right: 3px;
}
...
.main .cols .col-cnt { width: 183px; float: right; position: relative; }
...
```

[image: after edit]

This CSS worked:

```css
.trt {
    z-index: 9999999999999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    right: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

set `col-cnt` div to `position: relative` set `trt` to `position: absolute; bottom:3px; right:3px;` that should get you where you need to be.. also, `trt` should be a class if it is being reused

Comment: Please see updated image in my question. it is aligned right but vertically centered.

Comment: the RIGHT is working fine but the BOTTOM has no effect on it.

Comment: Answer correct but worth to notice that if we understand "float" in the question as "and keep the float: right feature, this answer breaks wrapping of rest of content

Answer (score 6):

First at all, you must set parent of #trt to relative.

```
#parent-of-trt  {
   position: relative;
}
```

And set #trt to absolute

```
#trt {
   position: absolute;
   left: 4px;
   bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your float: right isn't working because of a width issue on the `#trt` div.  Basically it's extending 100% of the width and so it can't technically go left or right.  Instead of floating, just use...

```
#trt { text-align: right; }
```

???

As for getting it pushed down onto that grey line, add some `margin-top` to `#trt` to do that...

Other solution would be to use `position: absolute;` but would be less preferable.

Comment: McMastermind worked to position it right but now it's centered. Please see updated image/code above. Margin-top has no effect on it.

Comment: See my edit, add margin-top to the trt div to push it down some.

Comment: margin-top: 200px or margin-top: 20px had no effect on how far it goes down.

Comment: Ah, that's because you are using position: absolute;....  

It is positioning it 3 px from the bottom of .col-cnt...  Can you provide a JSFiddle please?

Comment: I used TOP instead of BOTTOM as per Mastermind and it worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `position: absolute;` instead of `relative`

Answer (score 0):

change position as fixed like following:

`position:fixed;`

it should work.